# Jax-rs QueryParam causing multi-thread issue when defined as the resource POJO member field

Tags: multithreading, rest, servlets, cxf, jax-rs

Question Description :

I have a JAX-RS resource pojo defined as below (outside is cxf container inregrated with spring, running in a tomcat)

```
@Path("/test/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestService {

    @PathParam("id") private String id;

    @GET
    public Response get() throws Exception{
        return Response.ok().entity(id).build();
    }
}
```

Then I use jmeter to send some load with auto-increasing "id" parameters to the server. And I got this issue : the id in the response doesn't match that was sent.
E.g. request "localhost:8090/test/100" will get a "87" in the response.
And The frequency of error increases by using more client threads or making the handler method slower like this :

```
@GET
public Response get() throws Exception{
    return Response.ok().entity(id).build();
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

My thinking and confusion: The TestService is used as a singleton and since the "id" is a shared
field, so it MAY cause inconsistency issue when there are multiple threads running the "get()" function because it uses the shared "id". And then I put the "id" into the method parameter issue was resolved :

```
@Path("/test/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestService {

    @GET
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") String id) throws Exception{
        return Response.ok().entity(id).build();
    }
}
```

My confusion is : If this is a existing problem, I did saw lots of places and articles with the first style of using @PathParam, even in the jsr-339-jaxrs final spec?

![code snippets from jsr-339-jaxrs final spec][1]

Or both style there is good but I made some mistakes on my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you specify singleton scope in your dependency injection config? If it's instantiated in a request scope it should work, whereas if it's singleton scope it will cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the docs seems to suggest that in CXF, with Spring, resources are treated as singletons by default:

> "By default, the service beans which are referenced directly from the jaxrs:server endpoint declarations are treated by the runtime as singleton JAX-RS root resources"

[Apache CXF Docs - Lifecycle Management Section](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-Lifecyclemanagement)

But in Jersey, the JAX-RS reference implementation, root resources are treated as dependent scoped (a new one is created on each request) unless otherwise specified.

> By default the life-cycle of root resource classes is per-request which, namely that a new instance of a root resource class is created every time the request URI path matches the root resource.

See section 3.4 in https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

So, if you are using CXF with Spring, your resources are likely singletons unless you configure them to be Spring Prototypes.  With dependent scoped injection, @PathParam as an instance field should be fine, but in a singleton scope it you would expect to see issues like you describe.

Comment: Very interesting. It seems that in that case, CXF ignores the JAX-RS specification, which requests explicitly an implementation to act as Jersey.

Comment: Hi Andrei, yeah I think CXF is mainly for JAX-WS things. As you can see from their docs there are so few guides about Rest support, even though they claimed fully implement and support the jax-rs api. The reason I choose CXF is it has seamless integration with Spring. Now I switched to Jersey and got jersey-spring for DI supports. Then doing rest things becomes much easier than before because jersey has  pretty nice docs.